# How to render a form as a table

Tags: php, drupal

I've created a form that has the following structure

```
function myfunction(){

      $form['myform']['row1']['field1'] = array(
        //type, title, etc.
      ); 
      $form['myform']['row1']['field2'] = array(
        //type, title, etc.
      ); 
      $form['myform']['row1']['field3'] = array(
        //type, title, etc.
      ); 


      $form['myform']['row2']['field1'] = array(
        //type, title, etc.
      ); 
      $form['myform']['row2']['field2'] = array(
        //type, title, etc.
      ); 
      $form['myform']['row2']['field3'] = array(
        //type, title, etc.
      ); 
}
```

but I'd like to render it as a table in the following format with a head row if possible.

```
                       Col 1              Col 2                Col 3
----------------------------------------------------------------------           
Row 1                  Field 1            Field 2              Field 3
Row 2                  Field 1            Field 2              Field 3
Row 3                  Field 1            Field 2              Field 3
```

What format should I follow to get Drupal to render the form as a table?

P.S. `Col 1 = select`, `Col 2 = checkbox`, `Col 3 = texfield` and the very first column is the `row #` `Row1, Row2, Row3`.

**Edit: doesn't drupal have something that you could give it a form and it will automatically produce that colored row, white row look?**

Comment: What is the actual content of the one of the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that may help.

```
function yourmodule_yourform($form){

    $header = array(
        'field1', 'field2', 'field3',
    );

    $rows = array();

    $rows[] = array('data' => array(drupal_render($form['row1']['field1'], drupal_render($form['row1']['field2'], drupal_render($form['row1']['field3'])))));

    $rows[] = array('data' => array(drupal_render($form['row2']['field1'], drupal_render($form['row2']['field2'], drupal_render($form['row2']['field3'])))));

    $rows[] = array('data' => array(drupal_render($form['row3']['field1'], drupal_render($form['row3']['field2'], drupal_render($form['row3']['field3'])))));

    $output = theme('table', $header, $rows, array('id' => 'yourid'));
    $output .= drupal_render($form);

    return $output;

}
```

UPD.

Also you can play around with class attribute like this:

```
$header = array(
        'Title', array('data' => t('Checkbox one'), 'class' => 'checkbox'), array('data' => t('Checkbox two'), 'class' => 'checkbox'),
    );

$row[] = drupal_render($form['name']);

$row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form['checkbox_one']), 'class' => 'checkbox');

$row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form['checkbox_two'], 'class'=> 'checkbox');

$rows[] = $row;

$output = theme('table', $header, $rows, array('id' => 'yourid'));
$output .= drupal_render($form);

return $output;
```

I'm not sure whether you can use some other classes besides checkbox. Pretty sure you can use weight somehow, but not sure about the others.

Comment: You should probably do this in a form's theme or preprocess function, right ?

Comment: You do it in the form's theme function, not preprocess.

Comment: I've been trying to make this code work for an hour. Do you have a running sample code?

Answer (score 2):

This should work. I'm not sure what's in your actual arrays (the part that's commented out), but this should display it all as a table. I'm using implode because I don't know what is in those arrays, but this will display it with a space between each item in the cell array.

```
echo '<table>';

echo '<tr><th></th><th>Cell 1</th><th>Cell 2</th><th>Cell 3</th></tr>';

foreach( $form['myform'] as $row )
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $row as $cell )
    {
        echo '<td>' . implode(' ',$cell) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Also I realize this isn't exactly pretty. If any of it doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll esplain.

Comment: Also of note, I don't know anything about drupal. So some of the other answers might be better suited for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

assume row1, row2 are fieldset.
**If you want to theme form and place fields into table:**


Define your form id (you can look it in html source of your form: type="hidden" name="form_id" value="YOURFORMID", it's should be like "YOURMODULENAME_myform").
Add this function in template.php (or add array if already function there)

```
function YOURTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items[] = array(
    'YOURMODULENAME_myform' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'YOURMODULENAME_myform' 
        // This is file name of your themer of form
    ),
   ...
   return $items;
```

Add file into your theme: YOURMODULENAME_myform.tpl.php
Place code, like this:

```
<table><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <?php print drupal_render($form['row1']['field1'] );  ?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php print drupal_render($form['row1']['field2'] );  ?>
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>

</tbody></table>

<?php print drupal_render($form); // Required! ?>
```

Refresh cache in Perfomance page.

**If you want to theme result of form, then just theme page output (like node-TYPE.tpl.php)**

Answer (score 1):

I would build arrays of `drupal_render()`-ed output from the form's `element_children` that can be themed using `theme('table', $header, $rows, $attributes = array(), $caption = NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can individually override each form item's theme function by setting the `#theme` property.

```
$form = array();
...
$form['#theme'] = 'my_custom_form_theme_function';
...
$form['item'] = array(
  ...
  '#theme' => 'my_custom_item_theme_function',
);
```

You have to define `theme_my_custom_form_theme_function` and `theme_my_custom_item_theme_function` and register them with `hook_theme`.